# Why can't I execute mysql without the full path?

Tags: macos, terminal, mysql

At my terminal, I can't `cd` to the folder containing `mysql` and call it.

```
TimsMacBookAir:/ tim$ cd /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/
TimsMacBookAir:bin tim$ mysql
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

If I execute the file by using the whole path, it works

```
TimsMacBookAir:bin tim$ /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 7
Server version: 5.5.38 Source distribution
```

Why is that?

Comment: Because mysql is not in your PATH variable in which case you need the absolute path to the executable or you can `cd` to the directory where the executable file resides and call it like this-`./mysql`

Comment: Just use `./mysql` or add `.` to you `PATH`  which is not usually recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current directory is usually not in the `PATH` variable (the variable contains all the directories where to look for an executable).

If you type `echo $PATH` you will see that `.` is not in the semicolon separated list of directories.